# Is there a way that we can interpret the difference between linear and non-linear PDEs geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

Consider the linear equation
$$
f_1(x) = 2x+3
$$
We can interpret the fact that this equation is linear geometrically as meaning that the plot of this function is a straight line.

When dealing with PDEs, is there a way of interpreting linearity in this kind of geormetric fashion?

If so, how can we interpret the difference between linear, semilinear and quasilinear PDEs in this way?